# Group statements, avoid pagebreak

Tags: page-breaking, environments

I make an FAQ document, for this I redefined environments like

```
\newenvironment{question} % no indenting, bold and new paragraph
{\setlength\parindent{0pt}\bfseries}
{\par}

\newenvironment{answer} % v spacing at the end
{}
{\vspace*{10pt}}
```

(This is likely to change in the near future.)

In the document, I have brief questions and answers:

```
\begin{question}
    Why?
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    I don't know!
\end{answer}
```

How can I "group" question and answer in order to not have a pagebreak between question and answer?

Comment: you might try `\par\nobreak` as the closing part of the `question` environment.  this won't prevent breaks *within* either the question or answer though, so to encourage a break *before* a question, start that environment with `\par\penalty-1000`.  (`\goodbreak` is defined as `\par\penalty-500`, so you probably want something stronger than that.)  you'll probably still need to use `\newpage` sometimes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest solution is to define a wrapper environment such as

```
\newenvironment{qn}{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}
```

then use

```
\begin{qn}
\begin{question}
    Why?
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
    I don't know!
\end{answer}
\end{qn}
```

Comment: Any explanation whatsoever, would be just fantastic and greatly appreciated! Is it the `minipage` command that prevents pagebreaks? The official documentation does not mention it at all (http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/minipage.html) :/

Comment: @Domi yes that is essentially minipage's only function: it makes an unbreakable box.